# php imagick distortImage to remove paper folds using 4+ point coordinates

Tags: php, gd, imagick

I am trying to flatten photos/scans using php and [maybe] Imagick and figured distortImage would be the appropriate function, but I'm not sure if I'm on the right track. The original images might be from a folded letter (as shown below) or just a flat perspective distorted paper that needs a slight adjustment to look square.

In my folded letter example, the image includes 8 corner points that I want to flatten. I have tried creating points (as shown with the red dots on the image below), and using these points I have taken it through `distortImage`
[image]

The processing is:

```
$imagick = new Imagick($tmpFn);
$imagick->setImageFormat("webp");

$w=$imagick->getImageWidth();
$h=$imagick->getImageHeight();

$distortedCoords = [190,120, 700,140, 690,370, 730,590, 740,860, 100,850, 95,580, 170,350];
$destCoords      = [0,0,     $w,0,    $w,370,  $w,590,  $w,$h,   0,$h,    0,580,  0,350];

// Create a new canvas to draw the dots
$canvas = new Imagick();
$canvas->newImage($imagick->getImageWidth(), $imagick->getImageHeight(), new ImagickPixel('none'));

// Apply the distortion
$points = [];
$points[] = 1.5; // Type 1.5 polynorminal (equivalent to a 'BilinearReverse')

// Blend the original coords with the destination coords....
for ($i = 0; $i < count($distortedCoords); $i += 2) {
    $points[] = $distortedCoords[$i];
    $points[] = $distortedCoords[$i + 1];
    $points[] = $destCoords[$i];
    $points[] = $destCoords[$i + 1];
}

$imagick->distortImage(Imagick::DISTORTION_POLYNOMIAL, $points, true);

// Convert the distorted image to base64 and display it
$output = $imagick->getimageblob();
$base64Output = base64_encode($output);
echo "<img src='data:image/webp;base64," . $base64Output . "'>";
```

but the result is still showing a left margin running at the fold angle - as seen here:
[image]

I was looking to straighten the result so that it looked like a flat scan from directly above, e.g.
[image]

Can anyone give me any tips on what is needed to get the desired output.

**Additional Edit (1):**

1. Note, the points I have in this example are just an example - there could be just 4, or 5, or 25.
2. I am not wedded to imagick - standard php(8+) gd would be ok too.

**Additional Comment (2):**

I wonder if DISTORTION_POLYNOMIAL 'works' [I've not seen any examples from official documentation [https://github.com/Imagick/imagick] on what this actually is capable of] - or if I just have to live with a four point DISTORTION_PERSPECTIVE.

Comment: I haven't looked into this too deeply, but it seems to me that this [polynomial distortion](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#polynomial) can only work with "rectangular" areas. In your case you have three of those areas you want to distort, not one: The upper, middle, and lower part of the letter. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: I would also say that polynomial distortion is not what you'd want as the image is "bent" along a polynomial curve, which is likely to distort the text. I agree that it should be broken into 3 rectangles, but I believe that a perspective distort should be used instead.

Comment: The problem is that the originals will come in all sorts of folds and bends - I cannot guarantee 2-folds/8-points, it could be 5 points, etc. I don't see it being a solution going down the multiple rectangles solution.

Comment: In that case you should define the problem more accurately. At this point the problem is: _"Here is this particular photo of a letter, and I want to flatten it"_. As I showed in my answer you could solve that problem when you use 3 areas. Please **edit your question**, so it contains all cases you want to cover.

Comment: You wrote: _"I've not seen any examples from official documentation on what this actually is capable of"_. Please see the link in my first comment here. Some basic knowledge of mathematics is required to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

I gave it a try, to solve your puzzle. As I said in my comment:

> It seems to me that this polynomial distortion can only work with
> "rectangular" areas. In your case you have three of those areas you
> want to distort, not one: The upper, middle, and lower part of the
> letter. Does that make sense to you?

I reworked your code to work on the three separate sections. It looks like this:

```
function distortSection($imagePath, $originalCorners, $destinationCorners)
{
    // open
    $image = new Imagick($imagePath);
    $image->setImageFormat("webp");
    // convert coordinates
    $points = [1.5]; // BilinearReverse
    foreach ($originalCorners as $cornerIndex => $originalCorner) {
        $destinationCorner = $destinationCorners[$cornerIndex];
        $points[] = $originalCorner[0];
        $points[] = $originalCorner[1];
        $points[] = $destinationCorner[0];
        $points[] = $destinationCorner[1];
    }
    // distort
    $image->distortImage(Imagick::DISTORTION_POLYNOMIAL, $points, TRUE);
    // extract destination
    $columnX = array_column($destinationCorners, 0);
    $columnY = array_column($destinationCorners, 1);
    $image->cropImage(max($columnX) - min($columnX),
                      max($columnY) - min($columnY),
                      min($columnX),
                      min($columnY));
    // output
    $output = $image->getimageblob();
    echo "<img src='data:image/webp;base64," . base64_encode($output) . "'>";
}
```

I made it into a function so it can be reused three times, and also note that I extract the distorted section before I output it. The code is not optimized in any way, it's just a proof of concept.

To use it on your image, try:

```
$imagePath = 'letter.png';
$destinationCorners = [[0, 0], [700, 0], [0, 300], [700, 300]];
distortSection($imagePath, [[190,  80], [700, 100], [170, 350], [690, 370]], $destinationCorners);
distortSection($imagePath, [[170, 350], [690, 370], [ 95, 580], [730, 590]], $destinationCorners);
distortSection($imagePath, [[ 95, 580], [730, 590], [100, 950], [740, 960]], $destinationCorners);
```

The result should look something like this:

[image]

It's not readable, because I don't have your original.

The most optimal way to do this would be to capture each line of text and undistort that, instead of 3 sections. You can estimate the amount of undistortion needed by the distance to the previous and next line.